# Pagination does not work perfectly

Tags: php, pagination

I have the following code:

```
$max = 4;
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? ($_GET['page']) : '1'; 
$init = $page - 1;
$init= $max * $init; 
$strCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'total_mytable' FROM mytable";   
$varstrCount = $crud->viewdatas($strCount);

$total = 0;
    if(count($varstrCount)){
        foreach ($varstrCount as $row) {
            $total = $row["total_mytable"]; 
        }
    }

    $result = "SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id_mytable LIMIT $init,$max";
    $varresult = $crud->viewdatas($result);
```

content of page:

```
    <?php

        if(count($varresult)){
            foreach ($varresult as $res) {                      
    ?>

      <h5><?php echo $res['title'] ?></h5>  

    <?php

            }
        }
    ?>

    <?php
                $max_links = 10;
                $previous = $page - 1; 
                $next = $page + 1; 
                $pgs = ceil($total / $max); 
                if($pgs > 1 ){   

                    if($previous > 0){
                        echo "<li><a href='".BASE_URL."/category/$previous' aria-label='Previous'><span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span></a></li>";
                    } else{

                    }   

                        for($i=$page-$max_links; $i <= $pgs-1; $i++) {
                            if ($i <= 0){
                                }else{
                                                                    if($i != $page{
                                    if($i == $pgs){ //if end insert 3 dots
                                        echo "<li><a href='".BASE_URL."/category/".($i)."'>".$i."</a></li> ..."; 
                                    }else{
                                        echo "<li><a href='".BASE_URL."/category/".($i)."'>".$i."</a></li>"; 
                                    }
                                } else{
                                    if($i == $pgs){ //if end insert 3 dots
                                        echo "<li>".$i."</li> ..."; 
                                    }else{
                                        echo "<li>".$i."</li>";
                                    }
                                } 
                            }
                        }
                if($next <= $pgs){


                        echo "<li><a href='".BASE_URL."/category/$next' aria-label='Next'><span aria-hidden='true'>&raquo;</span></a></li>";


                    }else{

                    }

                }

                ?>
```

The result:

[image]

And I not understand the reason for the active number stay right off the paging menu

In the code I defined  max-links for 10, but no show number 5 and if I define max links for 3 changes nothing , displays the same result as the image.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<li>".$i."</li>";
```

on the above line add up a href, seems like you have css formatting for `li>a` because of which you are not getting the required formatting on only `li`. so for getting better formatting for all paging links current, prev, next. you need to add up a tags.

```
echo "<li><a>".$i."</a></li>"; //in your else part
```

Comment: Thanks @ameenulla0007 was so simple I insert `<li class='active'><a>` it resolved problem with button. But last number has not yet appear before `>>`

Comment: I got it! `($i=$page-$max_links; $i <= $pgs-1; $i++)` I deleted the `-1` Thank you @ameenulla0007